# What is the point of the "Grasping Undergrowth" effect of the spell Druid Grove?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The 6th level spell *Druid Grove* (XGE p.154) lets the caster pick various effects for the targeted area. One of the possible effects is

> **Grasping Undergrowth**: You can fill any number of 5-foot squares on the ground that aren't filled with fog with grasping weeds and vines, as if they were affected by an entangle spell.

And the [Entangle spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle) works the following way:

> Grasping weeds and vines sprout from the ground in a 20-foot square
> starting from a point within range. For the duration, these plants
> turn the ground in the area into difficult terrain.
>
> A creature in the area when you cast the spell must succeed on a
> Strength saving throw or be restrained by the entangling plants until
> the spell ends

Since Druid Grove has a casting time of 10 minutes, it seems unlikely that you could successfully cast it during a combat encounter to activate the restraining effect from the Entangle spell (which has a casting time of only one action) and instead only get the difficult terrain. But difficult terrain is also overshadowed by another feature of the Druid Grove, *"Solid Fog"* that among other effects also causes *"every foot of movement through the fog costs 2 extra feet"*, which overshadows the 1 extra foot caused by regular difficult terrain.

**So, why would one choose to use the Grasping Undergrowth effect at all?** (apart from the role-playing aspect of being able to use it as seats or a bed)

Comment: AFAIK effects other than difficult terrain that cost extra movement *do* stack with difficult terrain. (And they can stack with each other according to the normal rules.) I'm pretty sure this is the case, but I'd have to check.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson While that generally is the case, Grasping Undergrowth specifies that the squares cannot also have fog, so unfortunatelly it does not apply here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Some additional spell effects are incompatible with fog

The final section of the Druid Grove spell description describes how you could have [gust of wind](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gust%20of%20Wind#content) or [wind wall](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wind%20Wall#content) in a couple locations. Both those spells disperse fog.

Placing Grasping Undergrowth in the location of where those wind effects are placed allows maximizing the effectiveness of the grove.

### Fog is implied to be a gas by these two spells

Wind wall explicitly says

> A wall of strong wind rises from the ground at a point you choose...

and

> The strong wind keeps fog, smoke, and other gases at bay.

This means that wind wall explicitly works against the Solid Fog of the Druid Grove spell, as there is nothing in either description giving an exception to it.

In addition, the use of the phrase "and other gases" instead of just "gases" implies that fog and smoke are considered gases, even though both consist of objects suspended in the air (water droplets and soot particles, respectively.) Therefore, if fog is a gas, then gust of wind is effective against the fog as it

> disperses gas or vapor.

A DM is of course free to rule how they like, but rules just do what they say they do, and without additional arguments from the rules, these effects affect the solid fog of Druid Grove, and so make it meaningful to use the "Grasping Undergrowth" in area affected by the wind spells.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Solid Fog lacks the "can be dispersed by wind" text that *fog cloud* has.  Gust of Wind says it disperses "gas or vapor" but I'm not sure solid fog counts; it seems like it's more illusion than actual fog based on how it looks to people who are in on it.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym If *solid fog* were illusory, the spell would be an Illusion, and it isn’t. Also, for what it’s worth, [*solid fog* in previous editions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/solidFog.htm) explicitly covered wind—harder to remove than *fog cloud*, but *gust of wind* and *wind wall* are still up to the task.

Comment: @KRyan Absurd argument. *Druid grove* is an abjuration that creates a number of effects that, strictly speaking, arise from other schools. It's not transmutation, yet it *awakens* guardian trees.  It isn't conjuration, yet it creates an *entangle* effect. Solid fog may be another conjuration or an illusion, but either way "this spell isn't marked as an illusion spell" doesn't hold any water as an argument..  The arcane equivalent, *guards and wards*, works the same way, including conjured webs, confusing enchantments, illusory lights, evoked wind, and more, but it's technically an abjuration.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I didn’t realize that *solid fog* was not a separate spell in its own right, as *entangle* is. In previous editions, *solid fog* has been its own thing, and it’s been a Conjuration. I still don’t buy that *druid grove* in any way implies that its *solid fog* effect is merely illusion—there’s literally nothing in there that suggests that in any way to me.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I added to my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: @KRyan An effect that is opaque to some people and transparent to other people based only on whether or not the caster likes them simply *screams* illusion to me. It sounds a lot like how *image* spells act when you disbelieve the illusion. Conjured materials shouldn't be able to be opaque and transparent at the same time.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I disagree.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: Interesting point about selective appearance, but could the abjuration school explain the target-dependent effects?  No other text in the spell description even hints at it being illusory.  If it were illusion it wouldn't affect creatures with Truesight, but the spell description doesn't say that.

Comment: My initial take was that the fog would be unaffected by the wind, which is why Grasping Undergrowth seemed completely useless. But, the description says *"You can fill any number of 5-foot squares on the ground with thick fog"*, with no mention of illusions. And then *"To a creature immune to this effect, the fog obscures nothing and [...]"* which makes it seems like the (possibly) illusory part is beeing able to see through the (real) fog.

Answer (score 13):

### Let invaders see what you *want* them to see

Sure, you could just fill the entire 90-foot square area of the druid grove with solid fog, and just force them to be blind and walk at 1/3 speed while anywhere in the area. But maybe you have something more elaborate in mind. You could create "corridors" of fog-free areas that appear to be a path of least resistance, to lead invaders in the direction you choose. And of course, you fill all the fog-free areas with grasping undergrowth, to make it a bit harder on whoever wants to come through. For example, you could lead them toward the area of your spike growth, with a suitable shiny object in plain view to lure them over it.

Another example would be a 10-foot wide corridor with a dead end and a gust of wind effect pushing *toward* the dead end, creating a trap that forces anyone stuck in it to venture into the fog rather than try to walk 60 feet upwind in difficult terrain. Now they can't just change their mind and turn around and leave after walking 5 feet into the fog. They *have* to push through 30 or so feet of solid fog if they want to escape.

Placing narrow corridors between fog walls also encourages a group of enemies to line up in a way that may be more convenient for someone aiming to catch all of them in a spell's area.

### Make the spell harder to dispel

*Druid Grove* has a special interaction with *Dispel Magic*:

> A dispel magic cast on the area, if successful, removes only one of the following effects, not the entire area. That spell’s caster chooses which effect to end. Only when all its effects are gone is this spell dispelled.

If you fill the entire area with fog, then a single *Dispel Magic* could remove all the fog, and with it the main impediment to movement within the grove. If you mix fog and undergrowth, you force an invader to cast *Dispel Magic* twice instead of once if they want to have unrestricted movement through the spell's area. (And that's assuming both castings are successful.)

Comment: I like the idea of making it basically your own lair with its own unique layout and hidden paths.

Answer (score 8):

### It's probably a mistake.

You're correct -- difficult terrain is functionally the only effect you're going to get out of this, and is strictly inferior to Solid Fog. But that's actually pretty strange.

If the design team wanted the area to just be difficult terrain, there's no need to invoke the *entangle* spell to get there -- they could have easily just said "it's difficult terrain". Because of this, I think it's most likely that this was an oversight on their part. I think they intended that the Grasping Undergrowth areas to have the restraining effect on creatures and forgot that *entangle* doesn't work like *web* (or *entangle* got edited to only restrain on the initial casting *after* they had written *druid grove* and nobody noticed the dependency).

### I'm not sure it actually matters that much.

That said, it's probably not all that relevant. While failing a strength save and getting restrained is bad, it's really not that much worse than trying to have a fight in Solid Fog, which is heavily obscured for the enemy and transparent to the caster's friends.

Restrained gives the target disadvantage on attacks, advantage on enemies attacking them, disadvantage on Dexterity saves, and they can't move from their space.

In Solid Fog, the target has disadvantage on attacks, advantage on enemies attacking them, and with triple movement costs, they may not be prevented from moving, but it's the next best thing.

The only real difference is the dexterity saves, but that's probably balanced by the fact that an enemy can tear free of restraining effects, while Solid Fog provides no real way to bypass it. It's largely a wash, in my view.

Comment: Perhaps this seemingly pointless cross-spell reference is a holdover from a previous edition in which Entangle worked differently? This seems pretty plausible actually, since 5E spells rarely refer to other spells in this way.

Comment: I feel like this might be the *actual reason* for the spell working the way it does, but without any official errata or other clarification from the writers, it is just speculation.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Well, in fairness, the similar-but-arcane *guards and wards* is written out the exact same way, with a series of references to other spells. Whether this issue arose because they wrote *druid grove* and later edited *entangle* to work differently, I couldn't say.  It's possible.

Comment: Myself, I'd make the Entangle trigger whenever someone enters the area for the first time on their turn.  In my opinion, the odds are high that is what was intended.

Answer (score -1):

**To Set a Trap**

If you have a grove, camp site or other location that you want to protect.
If you expect interlopers and can guess where they would approach (like along a deer trail, a well worn passage or near a doorway) or you can creatively encourage them to follow a certain path.
If you can set sentries to watch that path and take advantage of the spell's effect when the "bad guys" arrive.

This could slow down attackers enough to give defenders time to organize a response. The spell also lasts 24 hours (it can be made permanent too), so it's perfect for defense.

Why vines instead of fog? Archers cannot typically see through the fog to shoot those caught in the vines.

Answer (score -3):

The difference being that with the Fog it slows a creature down while the Grasping Undergrowth potentially stops them altogether while also giving them disadvantage on Dexterity Saves AND their Attack rolls.

Dont forget that mixing the effects prevents it from being easily dispelled as well.
IF you combine it with the Spike growth Spell as well then you have yourself a really nasty thing.

Move too much take damage.

Move onto the wrong spot you might be "entangled" and get damage.

Stay in the fog and be blinded while others pepper you with attacks benefiting Advantage.

Adding Wind wall making it nearly impossible to blow away the fog or attacking at range.

Gust of wind pushing you back into spike growth dealing another instance of damage and potentially needing another save against "entangling" again.

Do not attack Druids in their Grove; should be a proverb in all fantasy settings out there.

Comment: The restraining only happens when the spell is cast unfortunately, during the rest of the duration it is regular difficult terrain.